# MVC Renders Razor template on normal page load but not when Angular ngRoute gets it as templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, ngroute

I am using some 3rd party library that uses razor syntax to render the gui 'widget' that is used the client. It seems that this library creates some div and javascript that is then sent to the client. However, some issues are arising when trying to integrate it with Angular.  If I create a traditional MVC layout, in which the call is made to the controller which then renders the view, it renders fine:

```
~/Views/MyEditor/MyPage.cshtml: (
@model ...
<div class="col-md-7">
   @Html.{3RDPARtY}.Editor()
   .Render()
</div>
```

Other html elements on this page are decorated by ng tags and meant to be used as a template with Angular's 1.x ng-route.

in the angular routing controller...

```
$routeProvider.when('/MyEditor' {
    templateUrl: "~/Views/MyEditor/MyPage.cshtml"
    controller: "..."
}
```

In this scenario, when Angular routing loads up this route, the page comes back with all the angular tags intact and functions fine as an angular application. However, we find that the 3rd party has **not** loaded and has not rendered the html and scripts that it is meant to generate.

If we move the @Html.3rdParty.Render() to the main Index.cshtml, that is, the one that is by default without any Angular routing, it then renders and functions fine. Only when the angular router makes the request to that cshtml file does it crap out. It there any way to get it to render the razor properly when the router makes the call for the file?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code above correctly and understood your question:

- you are using the tilde `~` in your path in *client* script - the tilde `~` is only for `razor` (server side rendering)
- Additionally, *should* call the `controller` for the view and *not* the `cshtml` file directly.

Unless you muck with `web.config` settings in your **MVC** application you can't call `(cs/vb) html` files directly (restricted by default).

- default restriction setting `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>`
- In [Asp.Net `WebPages`](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-razor-faq) (a lightweight Asp.Net site that uses Razor views), it *is* enabled (`true`) and you can call them directly

Hth.